# есть модальное окно, как его переделать что-бы оно открывало много окон а не одно

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
function openModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
function outsideClick(e){
  if(e.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <form action="formdata.php" method=post>
        <div class="closeBtn">
          <i>&times;</i>
        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Признавайтесь: код писал однорукий ламантин? Ошибок больше, чем рабочего кода.

Comment: возможно .) так поможешь ?

Comment: Чем помочь? Нужно выкинуть и заново всё писать.

Comment: возможно есть на подобии  готовое, буду благодарен

Comment: с правильным кодом)

Comment: как понять много окон? То есть вам нужен функционал, который будет просто открывать множество окон в зависимости от параметра какого-то? или вообще чтобы сразу все открывалось?

Comment: это-тот функционал не позволяет открыть больше одного окна , то-есть мне нужно использовать 6 кнопок при которых всплывает разное модальное окно и все ..чтобы можно было использовать класс или id  вроде того ..@РоманТатаринов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если модальных окон несколько и они должны быть разные для каждой кнопки, сделайте универсальную функцию, в которой будет создаваться тело модального окна, и передавайте в нее нужные параметры, такие как id,содержание, и т.д.

Вот образец. Его можно бесконечно усложнять, применяя к нему нужные стили и элементы управления.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id='open_modal_btn'>Open modal window</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal_window {
  border: 3px groove #dddddd;  padding: 5px; margin: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#open_modal_btn').on('click',function(){
    create_modal('some_id','some_text');
})

function create_modal(id,text){
    $('body').append('<div class=\'modal_window\' id='+id+'>'+text+'</div>');    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2v1mqcc5/16/